# Convert black and white array into an image in python?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have an array of 50x50 elements of which each is either True or False - this represents a 50x50 black and white image.

I can't convert this into image? I've tried countless different functions and none of them work.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

my_array = np.array([[True,False,False,False THE DATA IS IN THIS ARRAY OF 2500 elements]])

im = Image.fromarray(my_array)

im.save("results.jpg")
```

^ This one gives me: "Cannot handle this data type".

I've seen that PIL has some functions but they only convert a list of RGB pixels and I have a simple black and white array without the other channels.

Comment: To clarify: If you have an array [True, False] then you want that to represent two pixels, one being black and the other white?

Comment: If the value is True - it means white pixel if it's False it's a black pixel. So each element corresponds to just one pixel. That's why I have just 2500 elements for each 50x50 image.

Comment: And you just have one numpy array of length 2500? In other words, it's a 2500x1 array and not a 50x50 array?

Comment: I have 50x50 array. 50 elements of 50 pixels - of which one element is one row. I can't seem to convert this into a simple 50x50 image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you should make your array 50x50 instead of a 1d array:

```
my_array = my_array.reshape((50, 50))
```

Then, to get a standard 8bit image, you should use an unsigned 8-bit integer dtype:

```
my_array = my_array.reshape((50, 50)).astype('uint8')
```

But you don't want the `True`s to be `1`, you want them to be `255`:

```
my_array = my_array.reshape((50, 50)).astype('uint8')*255
```

Finally, you can convert to a PIL image:

```
im = Image.fromarray(my_array)
```

I'd do it all at once like this:

```
im = Image.fromarray(my_array.reshape((50,50)).astype('uint8')*255)
```

Comment: I've tried your solution and got: ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: This assumes that your array has 50 * 50 = 2500 elements. What is `my_array.shape`?

Comment: The shape is (50L,) - what does it mean? Does that mean that my array doesn't look like 50x50 array and I have some error in its structure?

Comment: It means your array just has 50 elements, and is only 1d (like a single list).  This seems a bit mysterious. What about `my_array.dtype` and `my_array.size`?

Comment: my_array.dtype is Object and my_array.size is 50

Comment: Oh I see, somehow your array is not a uniform array, but is a like an array of arrays.  How do you create your array?  What is `my_array[0].dtype`?

Comment: my_array[0].dtype shows Attribute Error: 'list' has no attribute dtype, I deleted one pair of outer parenthesis and I think it might have been causing some of the problems. But when I run your solution on this modified array I get: Value Error: only 2 non-keyword arguments accepted.

Comment: I've reshaped the array, thanks to your helpful post. But I get a black square as the saved image - even though the picture has clearly both white and black pixels. Could you help me this last time? Your code seems to always save black pixels even if you manually create a small 2x2 picture and enter some artibrary pixel values.

Comment: Is `my_array.dtype` now `bool`?

Comment: Yes, it is bool. The code always saves a black square. Does this have something to do with the uint8 type?

Comment: Oh, they are 0 and 1 and jpeg runs 0 to 255.  Try multiplying the array by 255 :P

Comment: It works! Thank you! Though the result doesn't seem to look like I anticipated. :) http://i.imgur.com/yvv1bje.jpg This is apparently how my neural network (RBM) visualizes a mug. lol Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Wow, very cool, thanks for sharing the image!  Doesn't look like a mug nor a donut.